# Removing cells with duplicate values from Range object

Tags: vba, excel

I've a `Range` object which its cells contains duplicate values.

How can I obtain a `Range` object with all duplicate values left out?

Although not required, assume that every first unique occurrence should be in the resulting `Range` object.

Answer (score 0):

Record a macro while issuing the Data, Remove duplicates command as that is precisely what that does.